# How to keep json file format valid while using Json.net library to write new record to existing to json file?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

my json file

```
[
   { "name" : "student1",
    "grade" : "A"
   },
   { "name" : "student2",
    "grade" : "B"
   }
]
```

My write code

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JsonFileLocation"], FileMode.Append))
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                using (JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    var student = new Students{name = name, grade = grade};
                    jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    serializer.Serialize(jw, student);
                }
```

After I write new student

```
[
   { "name" : "student1",
    "grade" : "A"
   },
   { "name" : "student2",
    "grade" : "B"
   }
]
   { "name" : "student3",
    "grade" : "C"
   }
```

Notice how it appended at the end of the file rather than after the last record and within square brackets. This is making my json file invalid. How do I make it so it will append new record within square bracket and with comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're appending a single student object JSON into an array of Student object Json. Notice the [] to denote the array.

You need to read the array, append the existing student object into the array and write back the array as JSON.

The below code reads the JSON contents from the file into a list of Students object (you might want to rename the class name to Student), appends the new Students object to this list and then writes back the complete list of Students into the file. The file will have 3 students objects in the proper JSON format.

```
var fileName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JsonFileLocation"];
List<Students> studentsList = new List<Students>();

using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
 var jsonStudentsText = sr.ReadAllText();
 studentsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Students>>(jsonStudentsText); 
}

studentsList.Add(new Students{name = name, grade = grade});

using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
{
 using (JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
 {
  jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
  JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
  serializer.Serialize(jw, studentsList);
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there easier way to append an object to json array objects without reading the entire file into memory. It seems like reading entire file to add one record seems wasteful.

Comment: nope. with files, there is no easy way to have random access to a particular record location. (unlike database etc.) you have to do nasty string manipulation (finding []) etc. if you don't want to read the whole text into memory and that never ends well.

Comment: @DoodleKana, wasteful?  The whole point is that you work with these objects in a strongly typed-environment.  You can't just then "insert" in to a text file and expect it all to hang together!

Comment: It seems strange that json.net framework does not have built in writer to json file with array of objects.

Comment: Well thanks @raja I ended up doing it your way. I will be still interested if there are other ideas to add to it without loading the whole list to memory.

Comment: The problem is when write it, because you file probably will do write others student, .net said  "the process dont cant read file, because it used by other process"

Answer (score 1):

try dessiarilize json to list then append a new object to list and serrialize it back to json

```
List<Students> studentlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Students>>(your json);
studentlist.Add(new Students{name = name, grade = grade});

JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\json.txt"))
using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, studentlist);

}
```